# How to allow users to submit forms but not view submitted forms?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

How can I make it so that users can submit Infopath forms to a form library, but not be able to see the contents of other users' forms that have been submitted?

I know I can change their default view, so they can only see 'My Documents' but I can't stop them just changing the view back to 'All Documents'.

Thanks.

JT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to configure this for SharePoint Online is to use SharePoint Designer, create a workflow and configure permissions upon item creation. [This article](http://www.edutechnow.com/?p=1259) provides a walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is even a better approach.
Create 2 list/libraries, Use workflow to copy from submitted location to secure location and delete original. Therefore  you do not get into unique permissions at the item level, which is not a good practice.

Comment: Interesting idea. If you do this though, do both lists/libraries have to be in sync? IE adding one field, you have to remember to add the field to the other list?

Answer (score 0):

Both lists are kept in sync because you have to create the form as a content type, then tell both libraries to use that content type. I know this is an old question at this point but in case anyone else stumbles across this there's the answer.